# Selenium 2 example not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I havefollowed the example at 
     http://www.qaautomation.net/?p=263

```
package net.qaautomation.examples;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

/**
 * Search Google example.
 *
 * @author Rahul
 */
public class GoogleSearch {
 static WebDriver driver;
 static Wait<WebDriver> wait;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");

    boolean result;
    try {
        result = firstPageContainsQAANet();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        result = false;
    } finally {
        driver.close();
    }

    System.out.println("Test " + (result? "passed." : "failed."));
    if (!result) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

private static boolean firstPageContainsQAANet() {
    //type search query
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("qa automation\n");

    // click search
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();

    // Wait for search to complete
    wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
            System.out.println("Searching ...");
            return webDriver.findElement(By.id("resultStats")) != null;
        }
    });

    // Look for QAAutomation.net in the results
    return driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText().contains("qaautomation.net");
}
```

}

to the letter but when I run it I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:59)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:48)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:120)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:81)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:244)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:183)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:179)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:92)
at com.google.gwt.sample.contacts.test.GoogleSearch.main(GoogleSearch.java:20)
```

any ideas on what might be wrong?  In fact several other examples I tried all give me a similar NoSuchMethod Error. EG http://thomassundberg.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/testing-a-web-application-with-selenium-2/ 
If you have any simple working Selenium2 example I would be grateful for a link.  Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to get started with Selenium webdriver I'd suggest reading through the documentation on seleniumhq.org and perhaps try the example on the following page it's a little bit more simplified.

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

I would also suggest using eclipse and staying away from maven and ant until you get a good grasp on webdriver, that's assuming you're new to these applications.

Comment: I don't use Maven or ANT,  just prefer to do everything myself as get better understanding that way.  I'm using Eclipse and have imported all required Jars,  Still get the same error.  Not quiet sure what the down vote on the question is for without any comment against it :( Considering I have been trawling through the documentation eventually you have to do an example and it's the example I have the problem with,  not the documentation

Comment: What's on your programs line 20? From the example it's "driver = new FirefoxDriver();" is it the same for you?

Comment: yes,  FirefoxDriver().  I'll post my code for completeness but it is the same as on the link I posted

Comment: I copied your code and ran it myself and it works just fine, are you sure you added the Selenium jar to your build path correctly?

Comment: Got it working,  I was using selenium-2.28.0  and replaced it with the jars from selenium-2.29.0 and it works fine now.  Not sure what is the issue with v28 but I don't have time to investigate properly. Verified when I put v28 jars back in that it fails again so it is defo related to the version of Selenium :(

Comment: Odd.. im using 2.28 and it worked without a hiccup, anyway glad it worked out for you